# LoadPlaylistByVideos method doesn't work for "youtube-ios-player-helper"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube-api

I have a problem with "youtube-ios-player-helper" in iOS (XCode / ObjC), i.e. with loadPlaylistByVideos method. When I use the code

```
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.youtubeId];
```

everything works well.
But when I use code:

```
NSArray* videosArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"xwtdhWltSIg", @"6Ejga4kJUts",NULL]; 
[self.playerView loadPlaylistByVideos:videosArray index:0 startSeconds:0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityMedium];
```

nothing happens. I don't get any error, but the playlist is not created and I see blank screen.

Could someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this [link](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/181) will help you

Comment: I've seen this link, but this doesn't work.

Comment: can i see your playvars?

Comment: I have no playvars. It is not problem with playvars. Whatever I try, the screen is empty.

Comment: well it could be the issue, i faced the same issue using playvars it solved me,for me the issue was origin i added origin to youtube solved me

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found is calling

```
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:something];
```

in viewDidLoad and then calling:

```
NSArray* videosArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"xwtdhWltSIg", @"6Ejga4kJUts",NULL]; 
[self.playerView loadPlaylistByVideos:videosArray index:0 startSeconds:0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityMedium];
```

in playerViewDidBecomeReady. This is the only way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this re-initializes the player webview, which is not recommended in the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

I solved it ike this:
Instead of calling loadPlaylistByVideos(...), call cuePlaylistByVideos(...) and set the starting index to the next index. (Telling the player that the next movies should be playing after the one you just started, to initialize correctly.

Then in the didChangeToState, you implement .Ended and call [self.playerView nextVideo]

This will only initialize your webview once and playback continuesly.